# How to create renewable subscription in Google play console

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription, google-play-console, auto-renewable

I have created a monthly subscription in Google play console, When I have purchased it in my app from real card.

Below are the details on google play store/subscription

[image: Google play store/subscription]

It says it will be canceled after a month but I want to auto-renew it, I also want cancel option in google play store/subscription

Where can I find auto-renew option in the subscription?

Answer (score 1):

From your profile I'm deducing you are testing your app in India.

A few months ago, Google has announced that it would pause new signups of auto-renewing subscriptions for users in India:

> Subscriptions will continue to be available as single access passes that provide users **a single billing period of access** (eg. 1-month access). At the end of the billing duration, Google says users will need to sign up again in order to continue their subscription.

source: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-suspend-free-trials-auto-renewing-subscriptions/

Maybe you should try to test on another market?